# cURL Image scraper gets redirected?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, web-crawler, scraper

I have a function here that tries to grab images from a webpage using cURL. It works for for most websites, but there are some that redirect the script some how. The website that is used as an example in my code below will redirect the script to a specific page on their web page. If I disable redirecting or limit it with CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, I get no content returned... What am I doing wrong here?

```
            function curl($url){

                $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; 
                    rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
                $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
                    */*;q=0.8";
                $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
                $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
                $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
                $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
                $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
                $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt' );
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt' );
                //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);

                $data = curl_exec( $curl );
                //$header = curl_getinfo( $curl );

                curl_close($curl);

                return $data;   
            }

            $data = curl( "http://www.missselfridge.com/en/msuk/product/dress-shop-299048/view-all-299126/dark-floral-panel-midi-dress-3273361" );
            $images = array();
            preg_match_all('~<img.*?src=["\']+(.*?)["\']+~', $data, $images);

            ...
            //then for each image in images, is displayed in html.
```

My browsers headers @Samuel Fullman

Response Headers

```
CACHED_RESPONSE true
Cache-Control   max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  17121
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 16 Sep 2014 16:27:42 GMT
Expires Tue, 16 Sep 2014 16:27:42 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Request headers

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie ...
Host    www.missselfridge.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
```

Comment: Maybe you should take it as a sign that scrapers are not welcome and shouldn't try to ram your way in anyways.

Comment: How is it any different from what my browser is doing...? I'm just trying to gather the images through a script and display them back to the user. There are many sites such as pintrest that use scrapers to allow their users to post images straight from the web.

Comment: @MarcB, I prefer to answer a question and assume the best in lack of other information specifically indicating there is something wrong being done, and then courteously point out other factors not specifically related to the OP's question.  But for the OP, yes you need to see terms and conditions on the site as far as copyright and usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the HTTP-REFERRER is not one of their own pages, and so they are limiting your access.  I do not see any referrer value present in your headers.

That said, you do have a way to troubleshoot this.  Obviously you have a site that works and that doesn't work.  For the site that doesn't work, can you view the image URL in your browser?  If not, then the URL itself might be bad (don't rule that out).  If you can, then compare the headers sent and received in your browser (through Firebug or other application) and compare.

Comment: Lets ignore the fact that i'm trying to look at the images right now. Say that all i'm trying to do is grab the page as it is and display the entire page by echoing the data grabbed by the function in a div. On the url that works, I get the same url returned back with all of the content you would see if you went to the page on your browser. For the URL that doesn't work, I get a page that seems to be their redirect page every time. And like I said above, if i limit the redirect, i get no content. What can I do to stop the redirect, and get the content to display normally

Comment: well admittedly, if you're wanting an HTML page/URL then no referrer should be necessary as you would also just type the url in and go.  I typically just exec() curl from the command line and am familiar with using -I (show headers).  Ultimately you'll need to figure out what a browser is sending that your curl function is not

Comment: I posted my headers that are sent when i visit http://www.missselfridge.com/en/msuk/product/dress-shop-299048/view-all-299126/dark-floral-panel-midi-dress-3273361 The page that gets redirected.. Could you take a look and tell me whats missing? I'm still trying to get a grasp on the whole HTTP header thing, so i'm not very sure